# Im not running anything on GPU. But GPU stat is not clearing my usage

Tags: python, tensorflow, command-line, pytorch, gpu

[GPUstat image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcjaG.png)

Im not running anything on gpu.
My ID is suil5044. GPUstat is not clearing my usage.
I think I finished it in the IDE but actually the code is still running on the server.

How do I kill my code still running on the server?
And not affect other users

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you could show us which process are using your GPU. Because sometimes many utils process use the GPU too under same user name.

However, please try,

1. Find out all running process `pid` which are using the GPU. This [tool](https://github.com/peci1/nvidia-htop) may help.
2. Kill process by PID by this command: `kill -9 <pid>` (be sure this pid is under your username)

Comment: nvidia-smi, gpustat, kill -9 <PID>. THANKS